# Extracting elements according to specific rules

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I tried to set up the flex-box in such a way that the blocks from the code snippet were arranged in the same way as in the picture.

The main assumptions are:

- if both blocks are filled with lot of text, the proportion of their width is 50%.
- If they have little text, they do not extend over the entire width of the wrapper.

How can I do this and is it possible using only css?

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: beige;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.block.l{
    background: blue;
}

.block.r{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block l">
      short
  </div>
  
    <div class="block r">
      short
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block l">
      long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
  </div>
  
    <div class="block r">
      short
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block l">
      long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
  </div>
  
    <div class="block r">
      long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Add `display: flex` to the wrapper...?

Comment: then in the second wrapper red "short" is cut off

Comment: There is no way to do this with CSS alone, you will need a script to solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires adding `display: flex` to the wrapping element to allow the flex-box to work.

If you also add a `min-width` to `.block`, you can also make sure that one side of the blocks is not too small.

There is no perfect case without using some script.

```css
.wrapper {
width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: beige;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.block{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    min-width: 35px
}

.block.l{
    background: blue;
}

.block.r{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block l">
      short
  </div>
  
    <div class="block r">
      short
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block l">
      long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
  </div>
  
    <div class="block r">
      short
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block l">
      long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
  </div>
  
    <div class="block r">
      long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help but this doesn't solve my problem. The text in the blocks will be random, so I can not set the `min-width`

Comment: @WalterWhite I don't understand, the demo (even if the text in the blocks is random) makes sens to your use case. Sadly, CSS & in turn flex-box doesn't take into account how much text you have to figure out widths. Is there any information you havent given which could shed some light on exactly what you want?

Comment: Forgive me I could actually write that the text will be dynamic. I want to achieve the effect as in the picture without defining static values like `min-width` in your example. This should be counted dynamically. I do not have any other informations to add.

Comment: You wont be able to say "if the text is short, show all of the text" with CSS without setting min-widths.

Comment: The `min-width` is a good fix, still, when there is a lot of text, as in the last sample, and when the text is different in size in one of the items, they won't be 50% each: https://jsfiddle.net/zadmLaos/

Comment: Yes that all makes perfect sense, but you cannot determine max-widths of elements based how much content. If you set the `max-width` to 50% then it will only ever reach 50% of the available area, even if the other side only takes up 10%

Comment: Yes, it will need some JS to get it perfect, and that would be overkill for its use case really

Comment: It is not for us to decide what is overkill, we simply can tell what is needed to solve the question.

Comment: I've thought about it and I am ready for such a compromise. I do not want to use the script and because css will not let me more, I decided to use `min-width` with a percentage value. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @WalterWhite Do note, if the text is longer in one of the items, as in 3rd sample, they won't be 50% each either, as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/zadmLaos/